# Use pace.js while file download is called

Tags: javascript, pdf, download, loading, pace.js

I would like to setup pace.js so it shows a loading animation while a pdf file is retrieved on server. But the default configuration of pace.js isn't doing it: When I click in the download link () my browser shows it's loading, but pace.js don't show up.

How can I configure it?

Comment: Are you downloading the file via ajax or it's an http request? A possible solution is when you click to download the file, call a function to start pace, e.g: `$('#my-download-button').click(function () { Pace.start })`. Docs: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/

Comment: It's an http request. I'll try this idea, but will pace stop when download starts?

Comment: I tried Pace.start, but nothing happened. Then I tried Pace.restart(), and it showed up. But the loading animation is finished way before the file arrives to the client. I put it to test by pausing the execution of the request in server side.